# How do I find a future date based upon the corresponding weekday?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, calendar, weekday

I am developing a calendaring system whereby events are created.  I need to be able to "roll forward" any event (which occurs on a single day) to a user-specified month/year.

For example, March 4, 2013 is a Monday.  I need to be able to determine, by the given month/year, what the corresponding date would be - based upon the weekday and its position within the month.  So, in this example the corresponding date for April would be April 1, which is a Monday.

Another example: March 13, 2013 is a Wednesday, so the corresponding date in May would be May 8.

If it were not for the fact that user supplied month/year is variable, this would not be so difficult a task; but since it is...

Comment: how do you want to deal with this case: saturday, week 5 of the month. Not all months have a saturday in week 5. so would you want to use the saturday of week 4? I just notice, you not go by the weeks, but by the occurance of a day. so still the same principle, not all months have a 5th saturday, so in that case you would want to use the date of the 4th instead?

Comment: No, the days will just fall off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a `Dates` table containing five columns, `FullDate`, `Month`, `Day`, `Year`, and `DayOfWeek`, and populated with dates well into the future you could easily do the following.

Assuming `@m` and `@y` are the user-specified month/year to roll forward to, and `@d` is the event date:

```
DECLARE @weekNumInMonth int =
(
    SELECT COUNT(1)
    FROM Dates
    WHERE Year = datepart(year @d) 
    AND Month = datepart(month, @d)
    AND DayOfWeek = datepart(weekday, @d)
    AND Day <= datepart(day, @d)
)

SELECT MAX(FullDate)
FROM 
(
    SELECT TOP @weekNumInMonth
    FROM Dates
    WHERE Year = @y
    AND Month = @m
    AND DayOfWeek = datepart(weekday, @d)
) x
```

---

Without a dates table, you'll just have to do some math:

```
DECLARE @DOW int = datepart(weekday, @d)
DECLARE @firstDayInMonth date = dateadd(day, 1-datepart(day, @d), @d)
DECLARE @firstDayInMonthDOW int = datepart(weekday, @firstDayInMonth)
DECLARE @firstSameDayInMonth date = 
    dateadd(day, (7-(@firstDayInMonthDOW-@DOW))%7, @firstDayInMonth)
DECLARE @weekInMonth int = datediff(week, @firstSameDayInMonth, @d)

DECLARE @corr date = datefromparts(@y, @m, 1)
DECLARE @corrDOW int = datepart(weekday, @corr)
DECLARE @corrFirstSameDay date = dateadd(day, (7-(@corrDOW-@DOW))%7, @corr)

SELECT dateadd(week, @weekInMonth, @corrFirstSameDay)
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/2893)

It's a little ugly, but what it does is:

1. Get the first day of the month with the same weekday as `@d` into `@firstSameDayInMonth`.
2. Figure out which week # `@d` is in within its corresponding month, as a 0-based integer `@weekInMonth`. This is the number of weeks between `@firstSameDayInMonth` and `@d`.
3. Get the first day of month `@m`, year `@y` with the same weekday as `@d` into `@corrFirstSameDay`.
4. Add the 0-based number of weeks `@weekInMonth` to `@corrFirstSameDay` to get the result.

Can you do it as a one-liner? Sure, just substitute your variables. Be warned though, it's ugly, and there's really nothing to be gained from it except lack of readability IMHO:

```
SELECT dateadd(week, datediff(week, dateadd(day, (7-(datepart(weekday, dateadd(day, 
    1-datepart(day, @d), @d))-datepart(weekday, @d)))%7, dateadd(day, 
    1-datepart(day, @d), @d)), @d), dateadd(day, (7-(datepart(weekday,
    datefromparts(@y, @m, 1))-datepart(weekday, @d)))%7, datefromparts(@y, @m, 1)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This was very helpful!  Just a note, your last "ugly" select statement yields different results from the first example. Also, datefromparts is only for 2012.  Thanks again!

Comment: @user2122092 Sorry must have been a bad copy/paste. And yes, datefromparts is only for 2012, but it makes it a bit more readable if you can and avoids a string conversion. Substitute as necessary.